# Is there a way to use headers of multiple registers in a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid which needs to look like this:

[image: Example]

I need to do this in WPF, so provide the XAML solutions that will create side headers for several rows in addition to the normal column headers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a code writing site - you'll need to show what you've done to begin with

Comment: **so provide the XAML solutions** wow at least you can trough a please there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the content in the data-grid using the group description and use group style to make it appear the way you want.